# Multiple Markers - GoogleMapsAPI 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, marker, infobox

in the beginning i want to say, that 
1. my english is not be best (im form germany(but i hope so that you can understand what i want to say :)
and
2. i know that there are many of these questions are already in this forum, but i am really new in javascript and so on, so the answers don't help me :/

ok ok , no i start with my problem :)

i have my googlemapsAPI so like the answer given in the folowing  [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

But now i want to have more markers then 5

how can i do it ?

thanks a lot

Comment: You can add more markers in a similar fashion by making more `['Name",##.###,##.###,#],`  so long as the last on does not have the , at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Literally all you need to do is add another element to the `locations` [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1],
  ['Another Marker', -33.950148, 151.259312, 6]
];
```

Assuming this is a serious question, I'd urge you to read up on the basics of javascript and programming in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the push-function if you want to add more markers as you go along:

```
locations.push(['Another Marker', -33.950148, 151.259312, 6]);
```

will add the marker to the end of `locations`.

But look at some tutorials for JavaScript, cause this is one of the basic things you should know to make your programming easy...